# Is there any tutorial for blocked type redirect in Moss

Tags: 2007, redirect

I want to redirect users if they type in blocked file type in a URL e.g.

> www.myportal.com/mysite/file.asmx

now in central `admin > blocked type` files I added "asmx", I want user to get redirect to another ".aspx" page. I know we can do it using HttpModule but is there any better way of doing it or any article that explains this issue.